# Invoking remote service using JMS

Tags: spring, grails, jms, activemq-classic

I have two projects one the service project another one consumer project,
Consumer project consumes the services of other project and the call should be async using JMS

I installed jms plugin in both of the projects

I have defined the JMSConnectionFactory in both of the project as below in `resources.groovy`

```
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory

beans = {
       jmsConnectionFactory(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory) { brokerURL = 'vm://localhost' }


}
```

**Note:** Both of the project are for now on same machine (i.e. localhost)

Now from consumer's controller I am making call to service from ServiceProvider project

```
jmsService.send(service:'serviceProvider', params.body)
```

In ServiceProvider the service is defined as follow

```
import grails.plugin.jms.*
class ServiceProviderService {

def jmsService

    static transactional = true
    static exposes = ['jms1']

def createMessage(msg) {
        print "Called1"
        sleep(2000) // slow it down
        return null
    }


}
```

now when controller submits the call to service it gets submitted successfully but doesn't reach to the actual service

I also tried

```
jmsService.send(app: "ServiceProvider", service: "serviceProvider", method: "createMessage", msg, "standard", null)
```

---

**Update**

Now I have installed activeMQ plugin to service provider to make it embedded broker (jms is already there)

and created a service

```
package serviceprovider

class HelloService {
    boolean transactional = false
    static exposes = ['jms']
    static destination = "queue.notification"

    def onMessage(it){
        println "GOT MESSAGE: $it"
    }

    def sayHello(String message){
        println "hello"+message
    }
}
```

`resources.groovy` in both of the project is now

```
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory

beans = {
    jmsConnectionFactory(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory) { brokerURL = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:61616' }
}
```

from consumer's controller I am calling this service like below

```
jmsService.send(app:'queue.notification',service:'hello',method: 'sayHello',  params.body)
```

call to method gets submitted but actually it is not getting called!

Answer (score 1):

The in vm activemq config (vm://localhost) works only within a single VM. If your 2 projects run in separate VMs try setting up an external AMQ broker.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using separate processes, then you need to use a different transport than VM (its for a single VM only), also, is one of your processes starting a broker?  If not, then one of them should embed the broker (or run it externally) and expose it over a transport (like TCP)...